# i can not define a list in vb 2017?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I wrote this line in Visual Studio 2019 on my personal computer, and it works well:

```vb
Dim coords = New List(Of (T1 As String, T2 As String, T3 As String, T4 As String, T5 As String))
```

This doesn't work on my company computer, which has Visual Studio 2017.

Why does this work on Visual Studio 2019, but not Visual Studio 2017?

Comment: vb.net and VBA are not the same so removing tag as this appears to be vb.net

Comment: It is a tuple, declare a class with 5 string properties as the superior approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would add this as a comment to the answer above but I don't have enough points apparently (weird system).

Whilst inferred Tuples like that might not exist in VS 2017, you can manually create a Tuple like so:

```
    Dim Coords As List(Of Tuple(Of String, String, String))
    '...
    Coords.Add(New Tuple(Of String, String, String)("Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3"))
```

This works even in VS 2010.

Comment: Could you help me how to convert this to array after using this. Now i have a coords as list and i want to convert this to array

Answer (score 1):

It works in VS 2019 because you have a list of **Tuples**. VS 2017 doesn't support tuples yet without [a bit of extra work](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/data-types/tuples).

> Tuple support requires the [**ValueTuple**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.valuetuple) type. If the .NET Framework 4.7 is not installed, you must add the NuGet package System.ValueTuple, which is available on the NuGet Gallery. Without this package, you may get a compilation error similar to, "Predefined type 'ValueTuple(Of,,,)' is not defined or imported."